# Get data using unicode value as parameter in where clause

Tags: sql-server-2012

I can get data using below query :

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MastDirInfo AS mdi WHERE mdi.DirName = N'テストモジュール'
```

but

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(255) = 'テストモジュール'

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MastDirInfo AS mdi
WHERE   mdi.DirName = @FileName
```

above query not geeting any data? how can i get data using variable in where clause?

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `N` to your statement

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(255) = N'テストモジュール';
```

Just try

```
SELECT N'テストモジュール', 'テストモジュール';
```

Your `WHERE` will not find the `DirName` you want...